# Reading Filter query set in Django framework

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm very new to Django , I'm trying to return the sum of total revenue attained by selling cars with respect to a particular site in Django . I have tried the  annotate method to fetch the results. I have written a query set using annotate.

```
mum_data = Cars_Showroom_Filter(request.GET, queryset = Cars.objects.filter(Site__in = ( "Mumbai",)).annotate(price=Sum('price')))
```

This returns me a filter object <users.filters.Cars_Showroom_Filter object at 0x00000264ABBA2A90> and I'm unable to read it . I tried using qs.count() but it returns me the entire query set list . Can some one help me with a way to read this particular query set value

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this,I hope it helps !

```
queryset = Cars.objects.filter(Site__in = ( "Mumbai",)).annotate(price=Sum('price'))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back . Well the normal way works fine , but I definitely need to get it through the filter

Comment: What do you want to get through the filter .....can you be clear please ?

Answer (score 0):

*`This returns me a filter object <users.filters.Cars_Showroom_Filter object at 0x00000264ABBA2A90>`*
[annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) return a queryset you can get sum of each indivisual like this
by iterating over queryset

```
for item in queryset:
    item.field__sum
```

this will return you sum of perticular field check here [Sum()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#sum)
what you want is [aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) this will return total of column like this

```
mum_data = Cars_Showroom_Filter(request.GET, queryset = Cars.objects.filter(Site__in = ( "Mumbai",)).aggregate(price=Sum('price')))
```

this will return you this value

```
{'price__sum': 127183} # this is random value it will return your price total
```

Comment: I tried using aggregate , but I'm facing **'dict' object has no attribute 'model'** error

Comment: Hello @NirmalKumar Okk my bad actually you're using ***djang-filter*** library I think in that you have to pass a queryset and our example it just return a dict value

Comment: If you just want to display total revenue of perticular city than you don't have to use ***django-filter*** you can get city name from user and pass it in provided query it will return revenue for tha perticular city ans if there is no record for that city than it will return 0

Comment: Hi Ankit, I have to use django filter as I will be calculating yearly data

Comment: You can do that  without using ***djang-filter*** but if you wish to use it than you've to read ***djang-filter*** doc to overide queryset and I think keep ***djang-filter*** for yearly calculation and for now you can use this one

Comment: Hi Ankit, Can you help me rewrite it ?

Comment: Yaah but you have to provide your code not here provide me your GitHub repo if it available on it